# React Native Navigation: Another Navigator is already registered for this container

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want my component to render a TopTab Navigator on the top and also a Drawer Navigator at the same time.

So something like

```
<TopTab.Navigator>
 <TopTab.Screen />
</TopTab.Navigator>
<Drawer.Navigator>
 <Drawer.Screen />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

However I'm getting an error of "Another navigator is already registered for this container. You likely have multiple navigators under a single "NavigationContainer" or "Screen" Make sure each navigator is under a separate "ScreenContainer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try using it like this, drawerNavigator holds as the main wrapper and inside it topTab

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
return(
<TopTab.Navigator>
 <TopTab.Screen />
</TopTab.Navigator>

)

}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

This should work, feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Tab navigator inside drawer navigator, you can search to get better solutions like "how we use multiple navigator in react native?"
visit below link
https://dev.to/easybuoy/combining-stack-tab-drawer-navigations-in-react-native-with-react-navigation-5-da